# 'setExtent' on vector layer not working?

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

As pre my requirement I want to set layer extent after drawing all the features. May some feature not visible after applying `setExtent()` function(this is my requirement). But it's not working. It's working fine with Tiles layer. Here is my code snippet.

```
 var cellLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            name: LAYER_NAME_CELL,
            extent:[12568355.379388269, 3268309.784291403, 12582419.792592742, 3275590.4112355663],
            source: new ol.source.Vector({features: []})
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var vectorsource = new ol.source.Vector({features: []});

        var cellLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    name: LAYER_NAME_CELL,
                    extent:[12568355.379388269, 3268309.784291403, 12582419.792592742, 3275590.4112355663],
                    source: vectorsource
                });
```

// add your layer, add your features... then

```
    map.getView().fitExtent(vectorsource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
```

you can try it here:
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html?q=vector
If you pan the map or zoom/in or out and then type this into your console:

```
map.getView().fitExtent(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
```

you should be able to set the Extent of the map to the vectorlayer extent.

Comment: This is not my answer. Actually I need setExtent particualrly.

Comment: can you explain why you want to use setExtent()?

Comment: Actually, the user input an extent and only that part of map visible to user. with out zoom or pan. some thing like this example [link] (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/layer-extent.html)